# How can you use firestore's onSnapshot listener when the firestore method is being called from node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have an admin site that has a react frontend, using redux actions, with a node.js app as the server which uses firebase-admin to do the work.

I want to use firestore's onsnapshot listener. but im not sure how this works within the HTTP protocol?

I can't use the firebase-admin from my frontend app, and i cant create realtime DB functionality from the backend within HTTP protocol.

**The goal**: to set snapshot listeners on my collections from rreact frontend without having to go through multiple authentication processes, considering ive got a separate auth system for admins with my express api.

Is there a solution for this?

EDIT:
my client app is currently initialized with firebase web app config data,  but because im authenticating admins with my own express server, the firebase web SDK hasnt authenticated with firebase, so i dont have permission for the data i need. im not sure if i need a service account, or a web app config with extra setup or what

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using the firebase-js-sdk on the browser?

Comment: Yes, I need admin permissions bc its an admin site @nvitius

Comment: You can add a firestore security rule to allow admin users to have access to all the data you need. That way you can call onSnapshot from the client

Comment: could you make an answer with a reference? ive been trying to use the firebase web sdk, but my setup has an auth system separate from firebase auth. so when i use the web sdk, im not technically authenticated, and thus am dealing with permission issues. and i didnt want to make admin user accounts in the main firebase auth bc that seemed hacky. i thought admin sdk could only be used in node environment? @nVitius

Comment: @nVitius ive gotten nothing but errors when trying to use admin sdk from redux actions. if you can use the admin sdk in react environment why are only node.js, python, java, go, and .NET listed in their supported languages?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't suggesting using the admin-sdk on the client. You will need to use the client sdk: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js. I don't know how your auth works, but it's possible to tie custom auth into the firebase client. I can write up a more detailed answer to give you some direction later today.

Comment: it looked like i had to use admin sdk's `signInWithCustomToken()` but the setup seemed overly complex @nVitius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to integrate the Firebase JS SDK into your client app using `signInWithCustomToken()`.
It's not too complicated to do. Though I suppose that depends a lot on how your current auth setup works.

The general idea is this:
Send auth request to your auth service.
Process the request like normal.
Evaluate if the user should have access to Firebase.
If they should, use firebase-admin to create a custom token and send it back to the user.
Use the token on the client to authenticate with Firebase.auth

You should make sure to have Firestore rules to allow admin users to access the data you need.

As an alternative that doesn't use the Firebase client SDK, you could have a long-running node process that opens an `onSnapshot`. Your react app could receive data from it using either [Server-Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) or through a [WebSocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)